# Need to map values of columns to another column as key value pair in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Sample dataset:

```
id,Amount1,Amount2,Account1,Account2  
1,10000,20000,AAA,ABC   
2,33333,30000,BBB,CDE  
3,50000,45000,CCC,BAA  
4,60000,65600,DDD,DSP  
5,45000,56000,EEE,CBMN  
6,20000,25000,FFF,FSS  
7,46000,25000,GGG,LAA  
8,85000,15000,HHH,MIS      
9,90000,10000,III,GML  
10,78000,8000,JJJ,SMA
```

Account1 taking values of Amount1,
Account2 taking values of Amount2,
ACC=Sum of Amount1 and Amount2

Final output should be in JSON as below,

```
{
"id":1,
"AAA":10000,
"ABC":20000,
"ACC":30000
}  
{
"id":2,
"BBB":33333,
"CDE":30000,
"ACC":63333
}  
{
....
....
....
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For scala world

create `case class Input(id:String,Amount1:String,Amount2:String,Account1:String,Account2:String)`

```
val df = spark.read.option("header",true).csv(inputFile).as[Input]
df.show
+---+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| id|Amount1|Amount2|Account1|Account2|
+---+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|  1|  10000|  20000|     AAA|     ABC|
|  2|  33333|  30000|     BBB|     CDE|
|  3|  50000|  45000|     CCC|     BAA|
|  4|  60000|  65600|     DDD|     DSP|
|  5|  45000|  56000|     EEE|    CBMN|
|  6|  20000|  25000|     FFF|     FSS|
|  7|  46000|  25000|     GGG|     LAA|
|  8|  85000|  15000|     HHH| MIS    |
|  9|  90000|  10000|     III|     GML|
| 10|  78000|   8000|     JJJ|     SMA|
+---+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

a simple transformation like this will give you a result.

```
df.map(x => {
       s"""{
          "id": ${x.id.trim},
          "${x.Account1}" : ${x.Amount1.trim},
          "${x.Account2}" : ${x.Amount2.trim},
          "ACC" : ${x.Amount1.trim.toInt+x.Amount2.trim.toInt}
        }""".stripMargin
    }).show(false)
```

we can also use other scala JSON parsing libraries mentioned [here](https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rdd.map` and create a dict, then you can collect it as

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: {"id" :row["id"], 
           row["Account1"]:row["Amount1"],
           row["Account2"]:row["Amount2"],
          "ACC":row["Account1"]+row["Account2"]})
       .toDF()
```

For json, you can use `json.dumps()` but it will make each row string, so you can use this hack to pass that in `json.loads` as below

```
import json
df.rdd.map(lambda row: json.loads(json.dumps({"id" :row["id"], 
           row["Account1"]:row["Amount1"],
           row["Account2"]:row["Amount2"],
          "ACC":row["Account1"]+row["Account2"]})))
       .toDF()
```

Comment: Getting error as :Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 43, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.

Comment: Need to convert the RDD back to dataframe

Comment: Updated the answer, feel free to upvote and accept as an answer if it helps

Comment: Still getting the same error as above. An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 43, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back